# Python selenium send_keys to inner table text area

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use `send_keys` for editing values in editable text area based on values. I have tried upto clicking based on value, but unable to perform `send_keys` to that specific xpath since it has dynamic inner table .

Below are the xpath :

first element :

```
//*[@id="productInformation-grid"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input
```

second element :

```
//*[@id="productInformation-grid"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input
```

The above element will have different values and I am trying to edit grid of only specific value.

Comment: What is the HTML, including (at a minimum) the section covered by your XPath query (from `productInformation-grid`, down)? What does your Selenium code look like, including setup? What is the stacktrace for the exception you’re seeing?

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_ and the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_.